# Delphi (FireMonkey) Android App won't compile: [Exec Error]

Tags: android, delphi, windows-10, firemonkey

I'm compiling an App in Delphi (Seattle) which did compile on my last PC. This is a fresh install of Delphi on the replacement PC. I get an [Exec Error].

I copied out the failing command and pasted it into PowerShell (Windows 10) to see the errors. I assuming it's a PATH too long but I don't know what steps to take to shorten it. All help appreciated.

```
"PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Redist\boost\win64;C:\Program
 Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Redist\boost\win32;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBase
XE7\IDE_spoof;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Bpl;C
:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32
\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engin
e Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Pr
ogram Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Pr
ogram Files (x86)\Embarcadero\HTML5 Builder\6.0\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Users\CDB_HDWP2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsA
pps; & "C:\short\sdk\build-tools\24.0.3\dx.bat" --dex --output="C:\Users\CDB_HDWP2\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects
\TCADS\BeBackBy\BeBackBy_12_3\Android\Release\classes.dex" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\R
elease\android-support-v4.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Release\apk-expansion.dex
.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Release\cloud-messaging.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x8
6)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Release\fmx.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\
Release\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-bil
ling.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-licensing.dex.jar" "c:\pro
gram files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Release\google-play-services.dex.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to completely re-install Java. Everything is working properly now.